# how to organize shared nodejs libraries with docker and monorepo using multi-stage build

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

My question is very similar to this on:

- [How to organize shared libraries with docker and monorepo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60401518/how-to-organize-shared-libraries-with-docker-and-monorepo)
  and
- [Git monorepo layout with shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64012316/git-monorepo-layout-with-shared-library) .

Neither of these threads has arrived at a solution. Then I found this:
https://medium.com/@xfor/yarn-workspaces-and-docker-39e30402b69b which advises that a multi-stage build be used like so:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
COPY packages/shared ./packages/shared
COPY packages/api ./packages/api

RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile --non-interactive

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/packages/shared
RUN yarn build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/packages/api
RUN yarn build

FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/packages/shared/package.json /usr/src/app/packages/shared/package.json
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/packages/shared/dist /usr/src/app/packages/shared/dist

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/packages/api/package.json /usr/src/app/packages/api/package.json
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/packages/api/build /usr/src/app/packages/api/build

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile --non-interactive --production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/packages/api

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Unfortunately, I don't use yarn for managing my monorepo and my Dockerfile is located within the app level of the monorepo rather than at the root of the monorepo. I am using jazelle to manage my monorepo and was wondering if I would have to create a `Dockerfile` for each app at the root level.